# How can I notify the valueChanges of my not-yet-created control after I create it with addControl

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

There are places in my code where I access the valueChanges property of non-existing controls. And I want these valueChanges to react after I create a control with the required name.

```
this.form.get('someControl')?.valueChanges.pipe(...some code)
```

However, I don't have this control at the moment and I want this code to work when I create it with:

```
addControl('someControl', new FormControl(null))
```

But it doesn't work. It works only if I call valueChanges immediately after creating the control. For example:

```
addControl('someControl', new FormControl(null))
this.form.get('someControl')?.valueChanges.pipe(...some code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it makes sense that you`re not receiving any changes because the formControl doesn't exsits.

Maybe this can help you.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
  console.log(values);// {someControl : 123}
  const someControlValue = values['someControl'];
});
```

Basically if some formControl emits a new value you will receive a snapshot of the current form state.

Comment: I tried to do this, but even if I follow the changes in the form, undefined is always issued. I think if I initialize changes to something that does not exist at the moment when loading my component, then even if I add them later, the changes will not include it since it is created later than the initialization of the changes.

Comment: Most likely I need to take advantage of creating control and disabling/enabling when I need it.